# Ios - action on button in nib file

Tags: ios, swift

Good evening,

I'm wondering if displaying a nib file as a subview is the more standardized way of displaying a subview when compared to hiding and unhiding a view of the same class.

Also,

How would i be able to set an action on the buttons in the nib file?

```
let test = xWork.loadViewFromNib()
        test.center = view.center
        self.view.addSubview(test)
```

Currently doing the above. Even though my xWork nib has a class with an outlet for a button, i'm unsure as to how to set an action to it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify your first question. As for your second question, how to set the action of a button in a nib, try this:

In your nib, create a callback closure:

```
var onClickCallback: (Void -> Void)?
```

and in your button's IBAction, call the closure

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: IBAction) {
    onClickBallback?()
}
```

Then, where you use your nib, set the button callback:

```
let test = xWork.loadViewFromNib()
test.center = view.center
self.view.addSubview(test)
test.onClickCallback = {
    print("Button clicked!")

    // Try this to dismiss the view.
    test.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Paul! Thank you for your answer! How can I dismiss the actual nib from one of the callbacks?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to dismiss the nib in the callback.

Comment: Paul, it seems like I'm unable to animate the entrance of my nib file. Everything worked perfectly fine when I had a view with 0 alpha and demonstrated it. However, is this a scalable way of programming in ios? It seems a bit rigged and unstandardized. Reason why I'm attempting to use nibs. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: I often use this technique, for example, to add buttons to custom `UITableViewCell`s, I set the callbacks for the cell's buttons in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
I don't think this should affect your animations. Since `awakeFromNib` will be called when your `loadViewFromNib` is called, you could put your animations there.

Answer (score 0):

If your nib file owner is its super view(or view controller),just CTRL+DRAG an target-action.